# How to add org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent to spring boot pom.xml file?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have created a simple spring mvc application using spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf and STS. Now I want to add an asynchronous task and need to add org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent as a dependency. The exact error message is

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Please help me to figure out how to add the missing dependency.

My pom.xml is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.demo.demoweb</groupId>
<artifactId>demoweb</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have the dependency in place. All you need to do is to set up a bean for the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. Example:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    pool.setCorePoolSize(1);
    pool.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    pool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    return pool;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This solution works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just add [`@EnableAsync`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) annotation to your configuration to enable asynchronous methods.